# Actions on Google support

Tags: raspberry-pi3, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm playing around with assistant SDK 0.1.0 .. Are "Actions on google" app supported on it? When I try to speak to my app it tells me " isn't supported on this device"

Answer (score 0):

Yes Actions on Google are supported on the Assistant SDK. Saying things like "talk to Number Genie" will hand off the conversation to a third party app.

Are you sure the device is transcribing the action's name correctly? It should behave like any other surface.

Comment: Yes I've tried.. on which device did you try? For me on raspberry pi with voice aiy also the numbergenie says "isn't supported on this device"

Comment: I'm using it on a Pi, and on my computer with the raw gRPC calls. Are you using the library or push to talk? Can you try using the text sample? Which locale are you using?

Comment: I'm using the library.m the code and locale are the standard one given with the voice aiy..also another user on raspberry forum is experiencing the same

Comment: At the moment only the grpc calls are working with actions on google. When they will be available with the assistant library?